# Why does the education section come before the experience section on careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I would hazard a guess that most people have a little bit of school/education information, but potentially a lot of work experience.  Certainly it's more likely than the other way around.  When I'm hiring/interviewing candidates for a job, their work experience is *way* more important to me than school information.  I think the CV page would showcase the relative importance of these factors better if the sections were reversed.  That is, the experience section would come before the education section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Agree. We're currently working on making everything re-orderable.</s>

To clarify: we permanently moved Experience above Education, and you can re-order any of the items *within* experience or education however you like.

This will be rolled out next week.

Comment: However a person reading lots of CVs may like it if they are all laid out in the some way.  The next customer/client should come first…

Comment: Thank you - reordering work experience items is essential - I've just put mine in backwards!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because people usually get their education before their (relevant) work experience, so the sections are more or less chronological.

Edit: I actually answered the question "why is "Education" below "Careers" on a traditional resume layout?"  I expect careers just followed the "standard", waiting for questions such as this to buck the system. :)

Comment: Well "first computer" comes at the bottom, so I don't know about the chronological explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I always put education information with my personal statement and a skills summary on the first page.  This is due to the fact that my education information only states I have a 1st in Computer science from Essex University.

I think for old people like me, the manager is likely to stop reading the experience session when he gets board, and therefore never find the education information if it is at the end.

Comment: 1st!!!!!1111oneoneone!!!