# Setting the order of Education and Employment on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

On the Careers site you add employment and eduction starting with the most recent first going to the oldest as in a stadard CV.

However then if I complete a course, get a new job or forget something, any additional employment or education are added at the end and in turn out of chronological order.

Is there a way to set the order and if not is this a valid feature request?

Comment: Planned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26273/why-does-the-education-section-come-before-the-experience-section-on-careers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employment now appears first, as this is conventional.

*Within* Employment and Education, you can now reorder at will.